# Pandas counter column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with the following data structure:

[image]

I'd like to create a new custom counter column grouped by user and code column. The intent is to increment if action is 'OUT', decrement if 'IN'. It should not have a negative number as assuming that occurrences of 'OUT' is always >= occurrences of 'IN'.

This is what I'd like to achieve, I've tried `groupby` and `transform` but didn't manage to.

[image]

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your input as code/text, not images.

Comment: can you provide an example data frame of which can easily used to reproduce the data .

Comment: if you tried something then show this code in question. And put example data as text directly in code - so we could simply copy and run it.

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry am fairly new here. Will note in future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new column with the Action column converted to integer values and then use `cumsum` on the new column:

```py
df["Action_as_integer"] = df.Action.replace({"OUT": 1, "IN": -1})
df["Instances"] = df.groupby(["User", "Code"]).Action_as_integer.cumsum()
```

As mozway pointed out, `cumsum` does not care about negative values. If you want to ensure there are no negative values in the `Instances` column, you may do something like this:

```py
def annotate_df_with_instances(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df["Action_as_integer"] = df.Action.replace({"OUT": 1, "IN": -1})
    df["Instances"] = df.groupby(["User", "Code"]).Action_as_integer.cumsum()
    if True in (df["Instances"].values < 0):
        raise ValueError("Encountered negative number of instances.")
    return df
```

Comment: You're a wizard! Really appreciate, it works.

Comment: @Unsullied but this is not a correct approach. If you don't want negative values, a `cumsum` won't work. Can you please edit the question with a reproducible example that would yield negative values?

Comment: @mozway I have amended my answer to check for negative values. I understood that this should not happen as an "IN" must be preceded by an "OUT". Hence, if that happened the log file (assuming the dataframe represents such a file) would contain wrong or additional data.

Comment: @max_jump I imagine this is not was OP wants, but rather to handle the potential negative values to create a floored Series as output.

Comment: @mozway since this data is a license checkout action, thus negative values will not be possible, it is just a matter of handling the potential negative values as @@max_jump mentioned. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

For SQL, first add a column as "flag" 1 for "OUT", add -1 for "IN", then do cumulative sum on "flag".

For Python, use numpy Series to do it should be faster.